# Python Selenium: click() cannot trigger event

Tags: python, selenium

I try to use selenium to mimic my action on a website to convert PDF files to EXCEL files. There are three steps to complete the conversion:

1. Upload the PDF file.
2. Input email address.
3. Click the 'convert' button.

I wrote the code as below. However, every time I click the button the page just refreshes without actually converting the file.

```
from selenium  import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://pdftoexcelonline.com/en/")

# Upload file
el_upload = driver.find_element_by_name("file")
el_upload.send_keys("/path/to/the/file")

# Input email
el_email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
el_email.clear()
el_email.send_keys("<email address>")

# Convert button
el_button = driver.find_element_by_id("convert_now")
el_button.click()
time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

This page works well when I completed the steps manually. What is reason that my code did not trigger the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is the not enough execution time. You can add some sleep after each action to verify. Treat it as workaround if work.

Comment: Thanks. But in my case, after inserting "time.sleep(5)" before and after each action, the problem still remains. I guess there are other problems here.

Comment: Actually the code runs pretty well in my laptop.The only tiny difference I delete the  driver.close() to make the result visible.(And the website popup success message but not received email:(. ) Your code should be correct.